# Node content is not listing for author

Tags: nodes

I have a view page with url user/%/plans.Which listing contents by a particular user.But listing can be seen only for the administrator when visit their dashboard(from admin/people)(screenshot 1).
But logged in user(content author) cannot see the list(screenshot2).

I gave all the permission to the author to view his content.But it is not working.Can any one give suggestions to solve this issue?
This is my views(screenshots 3 & 4)
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post view screenshot also?

Comment: Yes,i have added the views.

Comment: Who is the author of "test310"?

Comment: Stan Wyck is the author of "test310"

Comment: Can you remove permission and check? Already you are using the contextual filter for this right. Just try removing permission and check.

Comment: I have tried with removing the permission from views.But not worked.I have enable the permission "Bypass content access control" from the permission list of backend for this particular user role.Then it works.Is there any issue to give this permission to other user role except administrator role?

Comment: Is "House Plan: Edit own content" permissions set to that respective user(Role which user is associated)?

Comment: yes.I give permssion to this user role.

Comment: What about the content: Product Variations? Its used as Relationship. Can you take backup of view and try removing removing each field in view and check.

Comment: Product variations are a configuration from commerce module.Here product variation is attached as inline form to my node/add page.So node/add page(content type) contain fields of both from content type and product variations.This is a drupal7 maintanence site.

Comment: Check giving permissions for Product variations also. And I said backup view by cloning it and try removing each field and check with the respective user whether page showing content or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your Contextual filter should use `Validator` **Current user ID matches argument value** instead of **User**:

[image: contextual_User]

Comment: I cant see "Current user UID matches argument value" in my validator list?

Comment: Can you list or screenshot the options you see under the Validator option? It won't work with the User option.